# React Animated - Can't interpolate descending value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to interpolate an animation value(movement) to bind it to another animation(width change) occurring at the same time. Why does the input range not support descending values? Am I thinking of this incorrectly?

The animation would be moving in an upward direction (to an offscreen point) so the y Value would have to descend. Obviously the animation works fine when moving in a downward(incrementing) direction. Is this feature simply not applicable to my situation? Is there some sort of work around I could use?

Thanks.

```
  state = {
    movementAnimation: new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 100 }),
  };
```

```
  animateMove = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.movementAnimation, {
      toValue: { x: 0, y: -50 },
      duration: 500,
    }).start();
  };
```

```
  render() {
    const interpolateMovement = this.state.movementAnimation.y.interpolate({
      inputRange: [100, 20, -50],
      outputRange: ['100%', '50%', '100%'],
    });

    return (
      <View>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.card, this.state.movementAnimation.getLayout(),{ width: "100%"}]}>
          <Button onPress={this.animateMove}>GO!!!!!!</Button>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change inputRange: [100, 20, -50] to inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1]. Is that what you wanted to get? Or you just want to know why "inputRange must be monotonically increasing"?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code a lot
You have some minor problems in these lines

```
inputRange: [0, 1, 2], //Values should be in ascending order
outputRange: ['100', '50', '100'],// The numbers do not include percentages
```

You can now control the animation through

```
toValue: {x: 0, y: 2},
```

Now it works fine

```
<Button title={'GO!!!!!'} onPress={this.animateMove} />
```

I tried it !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a descending interpolation, do this

```
const style = a.interpolate({
  inputRange: [-value,+value],
  outputRange: [fromValue, toValue],
});
```